# Evaluating GCD, LCM expression plugging different numbers to get a certain number - where should I stop?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science

Here's a computer science problem I'm trying to solve:

Given an expression tree:

```
type expr =
  | GCD of expr * expr
  | LCM of expr * expr
  | Number of int
```

Write a function `insert: expr -> int -> int` where `insert e n` outputs smallest number `x` which, when plugged into `expr` instead of zeroes (we exchange every occurence of `Number 0` to `Number x`) gives `n` when evaluating the expression, for example:

`insert (LCM(LCM(Number 2, Numer 0), GCM(Number 0, Number 49)) 42 = 21`

The function should return 0 when reaching n is not possible.

And that last sentence gives me a headache. I've written 'brute-force' algorithm (for every integer j from 1 to answer we go through the tree setting all zeroes to j and then we traverse the tree again evaluating the expression, and when we find the answer we output it). But I don't have a clue where should I stop executing it - what is the condition under which we are guaranteed that there is no solution?

Also - is there a more efficient algorithm or my 'brute-force' algorithm is all that is possible?

Comment: This grammar you've written out is a foreign syntax to me, making it hard to figure out what you are trying to say. Why didn't you just say `|GC(expr,expr)|...`?

Comment: Basically main question is - when given an expression made of GCD - greatest common division, and LCM - least common multiple functions where some numbers are 'unknown' (e.g. GCD(4,GCD(5,x)), I'm looking for a condition which allows me to say that when we want the expression to be equal to some integer n, then x doesn't exist.

Comment: Hint: Using prime factorization of all the numbers, this is the same question with `min` and `max` replaced for `gcd` and `lcm`. I don't know if there is a better way than prime factorization.

Comment: A brute force approach would be to check all values $x$ from $1$ to $L$ where $L$ is the least common multiple between all numbers and $n$. If there is no solution in that range, there is no solution.